# Add Existing C# Project to Git-controlled Solution

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, version-control

I am having a heck of a time with this. I've read several SO and MSDN articles, but it looks like I just don't have the menu options that all the other answers are telling me to click.

I am brand new to Git. I have VS2015, with several Team connections (a "TFS" visualstudio.com, my own Git on visualstudio.com, and now I've connected to someone else's Git on visualstudio.com). I have installed Git Extensions.

I connect to my co-worker's Git project, clone the repository, and it appears locally. I can make edits to her files, and those edits appear in Pending Changes. I can stage and commit, and it's fine.

I can add files to her projects, and they stage and commit fine.

However, I am trying to add a csproj file. I do this in VS by right-clicking solution, choose "Add", choose "Existing Project" (it lives in a different directory). Locally this works great, but, my added project does not get the "lock" icon indicating that it is governed by source control, and changes to those files do not appear in "Pending Changes".

Trying another tactic, I have copied my project folder (PLEASE tell me this is not necessary!) into my local git repo (am I using that term right? The local directory where I cloned the Git project?). Suddenly, all of the added files appear in "Pending Changes"! I can stage and commit, they appear in visualstudio online ... but when I re-sync, changes I make to that project do not appear in "Pending Changes".

I have struggled with this for far too long. Can someone please help me? I feel like I'm missing a major step. Git is new to everyone I work with, and they have never had this problem (they may never have added an existing csproj before...).

Additional Info:
I can add the csproj just fine to my "TFS" team project (which doesn't help), but I cannot add it to my own personal Git project either.

I do not have any "add project to source control" menu options.

Comment: Yes you need to copy the files into your local clone. You need to stage, commit (changes tab) and then push (sync tab). After a push, it should be available to pull from the remote repo into your local repo.

Comment: @jessehouwing: I really do have to copy the source files locally? What if this was a project I wanted to use in multiple solutions? I would have to make updates in multiple places!
Also, I did copy the files locally (as a test) and commit the changes. They appeared in the repo online. I could get them as well (I deleted my local repo, re-cloned, and the project appeared) ... but they were not "source controlled" as in, they didn't have a lock icon, and changes I made didn't appear in "Pending Changes".

Comment: If it were a shared library you'd turn it into a nuget package and reference that from your solution. Or they could. Live in a second git repo and you could use submodules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use (add -> existing project) this way to add a file to TFS local repository. You should use the second way (copy the files you want to do version control into the local git repo). And then commit changes for you add files.

**Tip:** for TFS git repoject, in VS you can find a **pen symbol** (means pending changes) and an **up arrow** symbol (unpushed commits) in the bottom-right of VS, you can directly click the symbol to commit and push.

Comment: Thanks marina. Between your answer and @jessehouwing I understand now that's a new paradigm I will have to get used to, and that's fine, but this still doesn't answer the other part of the question, which is: when I did copy the project directory to my git repo, and committed/pushed/synced it, why were changes I made to that project from that point forward not tracked? Today I will spend some time duplicating this behavior (was it a fluke?), and also try the "git add" thing. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean not tracked? If you copyed a .csproj file, and then committed/pushed/synced, this file is tracked by git and the changes can be find in version control.

Comment: What I mean is, I physically copied the folder containing the csproj file to my local git repo and pushed. All the files and folders appeared in the online repo. I deleted my local repo and pulled. My project folder and files came down, however, they did not have the lock icon, and when I edited a file in the project, the file did not appear in pending changes. I made changes to other files in another project and pushed. The changes from the 2nd project appeared online, but the changes from the added project did not.

Comment: If you delete the whole local repo, when you pull, it will show error message because the working directly is invalid. If you only delete the folder containing the csproj file, this is the changes you didn't commit, when you pull, it will show `already up to date`. If you commit this changes, but local branch is ahead of remote,it will also show the message for you. Also you can notice the output window to check if there has error message.

Comment: Mis-spoke: not delete repo and pull, but delete repo and _clone_. Output window showed no errors. Proj folder and file appeared, but further changes to those files did not register.

Comment: The directory which you deleted and then created was cheat you. When you deleted the local repo, but the files were opened in vs. So you’d better connect to other VSTS project before delete the local repo. Or you can restart vs after clone.

Comment: @emery.noel, did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions. ;)